# Zxing Kanji characters in QRCode

Tags: c++, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to decode this qr code using c++ port of zxing decoder. Original image: [image](http://mobilocalbiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/JAPAN-QR-2902210442_8290bcb2a4.jpg)

After some preprocessing I prepared a clear image:

[image: qr code after preprocessing]

Now after decoding this code I'm receiving wrong text:

> rbNJ‰F http://www.biccamera.com/

in bytes:

```
83 72 83 62 83 4e 83 4a 83 81 83 89 81 46 0d 0a 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 62 69 63 63 61 6d 65 72 61 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 00
```

After reading the code above trough the website [the online barcode reader](http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/) I receive text:

> ビックカメラ：
>   http://www.biccamera.com/

in bytes:

```
e3 83 93 e3 83 83 e3 82 af e3 82 ab e3 83 a1 e3 83 a9 ef bc 9a 0a 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 62 69 63 63 61 6d 65 72 61 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 0a
```

The first part of the message is diffrent (I checked and the zxing library use Kanji decoding in the first part).

How to properly decode this qrcode to utf8 and store the result in `std::wstring` ?

My current code:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

zxing::qrcode::Decoder decoder;
zxing::Ref<zxing::DecoderResult> result = decoder.decode(zxing::Ref<zxing::BitMatrix>(bitmatrix));
zxing::Ref<zxing::String> ZXstring = result->getText();
std::string STDstring = ZXstring->getText();

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(STDstring); //bad conversion exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is really simple:

To read the code above you need to compile zxing with an additional library: `libiconv`.
After that this qr code will be decoded properly.

If you use Windows and Visual studio, this article about building libiconv might be helpful: [How to Build libiconv with Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302012/How-to-Build-libiconv-with-Microsoft-Visual-Studio)

In source code please check the ifdef: `NO_ICONV` or even better enable this library using CMake.